# Question about changing to polar coordinates

Tags: calculus, integration

I am reading some proof and I don't understand one step in it.

Let $G(x,y) = \frac{\Gamma (\frac{d}{2}-1)}{2\pi^{d/2}}|x-y|^{2-d}$, where $\Gamma$ is the usual gamma function and $x,y\in \mathbb{R}^d$. Then if $D = B(0,r)$ i.e. a ball of radius $r$ around $0$ in $\mathbb{R}^d$, then the claim is that with a change to polar coordinates,

$$\int_D G(0,y)dy = \int_0^r s^{d-1}C_d s^{2-d}ds = \frac{C_d}{2}r^2$$

I am guessing $C_d$ is some constant related to $d$.

> I don't understand how we changed $x$ and $y$ to polar coordinates and got the above. Because we are looking at $G(0,y)$, that means $x=0$ and so I am not sure what polar coordinate change achieves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the vectors live in $\mathbb{R}^d$, so saying $\theta = \frac{\pi}{2}$ as if we are in $2$D space is meaningless. Second, the function $G$ is a mapping from $\mathbb{R}^d\times \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}$, so just the $y$ variable is enough for a multidimensional spherical coordinates.

For spherical coordinates in $d$ dimensions, the Jacobian will be of the form

$$dy = s^{d-1} \:ds \:d\Omega$$

where $d\Omega$ is the standard notation for the variable that holds all of the angular coordinates and their Jacobians. Rewriting the integral, we get that

$$\int_D G(0,y)\:dy = k_d \int_D |y|^{2-d}\:dy = k_d \int_0^r \int_{\Omega} s^{2-d}\cdot s^{d-1} \: d\Omega\:ds$$

Since the integrand is independent of the angular coordinates, $\int_{\Omega} d\Omega$ is just a constant dependent on $d$, so we can rewrite the integral as

$$C_d \int_0^r s\:ds = \frac{C_d}{2}r^2$$

Comment: Thanks, may I know why $dy = s^{d-1}dsd\Omega$? Might be simple but I don't remember. I see the change of variable to be $|y|=s$

Comment: @manifolded take cases. $d=1$, $dx = ds$. $d=2$, $dx = s\:ds\:d\Omega$. $d=3$, $dx = s^2\:ds\:d\Omega$. And the pattern continues by design, because the purpose of a spherical coordinate system is to only have one distance coordinate, and $d-1$ angular coordinates. If it is the only distance coordinate, then integrating it should get me, up to a constant, the formula for volume in $d$ dimensional space, hence why the power is $d-1$.

Comment: I see, so the $d-1$ angular coordinates are captured by $d\Omega$?